# Using VBA loop within a Report to create multipe PDFs based on query field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been reviewing other answered questions on this site to find a solve for my issue without any luck so I decided to post this question:

I have an Access report "R03 01 Office Report main" that is based off the select query "R03 00 sel Rpt Office Report main". My goal is to use the field [Office] in the query "R03 00 sel Rpt Office Report main" to generate a pdf for each of the unique records in this field. Below is the code I have been attempting to use without much luck. Please Help!

Here is Select Query SQL:

```
SELECT tbl_Office_BLC_Data.Office, tbl_Office_BLC_Data.RM, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Clientonename, tbl_Office_BLC_Data.RAG_Status AS Rag_Stat, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Segment AS Producttwoname, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Revenue, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Net_Cont, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Variable, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Var_Cont, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Revenue-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Net_Cont-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Variable-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Var_Cont-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Revenue-2], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Net_Cont-2], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Variable-2], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Var_Cont-2], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Rev_Ex_Fx, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Rev_Ex_Fx-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Rev_Ex_Fx-2], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Net_Cont_Ex_Fx, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Net_Marg_Ex_Int, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Net_Cont_Ex_Fx-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Var_Marg_Ex_Int, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Net_Cont_Ex_Fx-2], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Net_Marg_Ex_Fx, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Net_Marg_Ex_Fx-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Net_Marg_Ex_Fx-2], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Variable_Ex_Int, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Variable_Ex_Int-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Variable_Ex_Int-2], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Var_Cont_Ex_Fx, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Var_Cont_Ex_Fx-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Var_Cont_Ex_Fx-2], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Var_Marg_Ex_Fx, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Var_Marg_Ex_Fx-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Var_Marg_Ex_Fx-2], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Var_Cont_Incr, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Var_Cont_Incr-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Var_Cont_Incr-2], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Var_Marg_Incr, tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Var_Marg_Incr-1], tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.[Var_Marg_Incr-2]
FROM tbl_Office_Data_Rpt INNER JOIN tbl_Office_BLC_Data ON tbl_Office_Data_Rpt.Clientonename = tbl_Office_BLC_Data.Clientonename;
```

Thanks!

Here is the VBA:

```
Public Function CurOID(Optional SetOID As Long = 0) As Long

    Static OID As Long

    If SetOID > 0 Then
        OID = SetOID
    End If

    CurOID = OID

End Function
```

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()

    Dim MyRs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fileName As String, pathName As String, todayDate As String

    pathName = "C:\O Reports\"
    todayDate = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")
    Set MyRs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Office FROM [R03 00 sel Rpt Office Report main]")

    With MyRs
        ' .MoveFirst -- unneeded after OpenRecordset()
        Do While Not .EOF
            fileName = "rpt_Office " & !Office & ".pdf"
            Call CurOID(!Office)
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rpt_Office", acFormatPDF, pathName & fileName
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

Call ShowMyMessageBoxOHRpt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to loop a recordset of distinct offices, open the report using the office as the `WHERE` argument of the `.OpenReport` command, and then output this filtered report to PDF.

Some VBA to get you going:

```
Sub sReport2PDF()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsOffice As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Office " _
        & " FROM [R03 00 sel Rpt Office Report main] " _
        & " ORDER BY Office;"
    Set rsOffice = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsOffice.BOF And rsOffice.EOF) Then
        strFolder = "J:\test-data\"
        Do
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_Office", acViewPreview, , "Office='" & rsOffice!Office & "'", acHidden
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rpt_Office", acFormatPDF, strFolder & "rpt_Office" & rsOffice!Office & ".pdf"
            DoCmd.Close acReport, "rpt_Office"
            rsOffice.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsOffice.EOF
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsOffice.Close
    Set rsOffice = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sReport2PDF", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Hi Applecore! Thank you for the assistance! I have plugged in the code but have received the Error: 3075 Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Office=Lux'. sReport2PDF. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, so as "Office" is a text field, the WHERE part of the OpenReport needs to use single quotes to wrap the value. I've amended the code to include this.

Comment: Thanks Applecore! I was able to have report run and it does produce multiple reports with the Office name however the data in the reports are all the same - the data is not changing with the specific Office. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This should work. Put together some VBA code that opens the report using the `WHERE` filter, but hard-code in an office name to see what is produced.